# gráfico de resíduos half-normal plots no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regressão, glm

Estou tentando realizar o gráfico apresentado abaixo referente aos resíduos no half-normal plot em ggplot2.

[image]

No entanto, estou enfrentando um erro intitulado Erro: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hnp.

Os dados podem ser vistos abaixo.

```
Stones <- c(rep("Stone1",1), rep("Stone2",1), rep("Stone3",1))
treat <- c(rep("T6",9), rep("T7",9), rep("T8",9), 
           rep("T10",9), rep("T11",9),
           rep("T12",9),rep("T14",9),rep("T15",9),
           rep("T16",9))
Samples <- c(rep("SampleI",3), rep("SampleF",3), rep("SampleR",3))
Count <- c(3,3,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,
           1,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,4,4,1,3,2,5,0,0,0,3,4,4,5,1,2,0,0,0,
           4,4,6,1,2,1,0,0,0,4,6,4,2,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,2,1,0,5,0,1,0)
Total <- c(rep("6", 81))
dados <- data.frame(treat, Stones, Samples, Count, Total);dados
dados$treat = as.factor(dados$treat)
dados$Samples = as.factor(dados$Samples)
dados$Total = as.numeric(dados$Total)
dados$Prop = dados$Count/dados$Total
dados16 = dados[dados$treat=="T16",];dados16`
```

O ajuste do modelo está apresentado a seguir.

```
resp16 <-cbind(dados16$Count,dados16$Total - dados16$Count); resp16
m16 <- glm(resp16 ~ Samples,
           data = dados16,
           family = quasibinomial)

Graph16=hnp(m16, xlab = 'Percentil da N(0,1)', ylab = 'Resíduos', 
    main = 'Gráfico Normal de Probabilidades')
```

O erro está aqui.

```
ggplot(data = Graph16)
Erro: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class hnp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a secção `Value` de `help("hnp)`, o objeto `Graph16` é uma lista de classe `"hnp"`. Estes objetos têm membros `x`, `lower`, `upper`, `median` e `residuals`, que são os vetores representados no gráfico.  Primeiro tem que se criar um data.frame com esses vetores e depois traçar o gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)

G16 <- with(Graph16, data.frame(x, lower, upper, median, residuals))
G16

ggplot(data = G16, aes(x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = residuals)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lower)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = upper)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = median), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Rui Barradas!!